# Html tags in one line

Tags: html, css

There are certain html tags which automatically are rendered on new line like if you place a `<ul>` tag after any other tag e.g `<a>` i.e anchor tag then `<ul>` tag will render after `<a>` tag in new line.

Is there any possible way in which this default behavior can be avoided and rather everything can be placed next to each other.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It depends on a number of factors such as the type of browser, your HTML editor softwer and more...

Comment: Every HTML elements have their own characteristics. For better understanding, check out this link http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/ (No negatives from me)

Comment: If you wanna have a good answer you should always give some code as and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell;` or a simple `float: left;` to achieve the desired result. Here's a working example relevant to your question. Try playing around with it:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    float: left; /* for IE */
    display: table-row;
}
div * {
    float: left; /* for IE */
    display: table-cell;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <a>Anchor tag</a>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will force all elements within the `div` to be placed next to each other.

Comment: Just a word of caution: Be careful not to use floats where something else would be appropriate. It can get pretty tricky to manage them when it's overdone. You should also try to avoid using any browser-specific fixes in your CSS. If a browser is behaving incorrectly, look for polyfills or more exclusive ways to correct them such as using [IE's conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include IE-version-specific style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, set the element's display to `inline`:

```
display: inline;
```

### Using a StyleSheet

You can do this by creating a stylesheet with an ID or class style for the element...

CSS:

```
#myHeading {
    display: inline;
}

.inlineHeading {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 id="myHeading">Inline Heading by ID</h3>
<h3 class="inlineHeading">Inline Heading by Class</h3>
```

Or if you want every element of that tag type to be affected:

CSS:

```
h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Inline Heading by Tag</h3>
<h3>Another Inline Heading by Tag</h3>
<h3>Still an Inline Heading by Tag</h3>
```

### Or With an Inline Style

You can also do this with an inline CSS style in the HTML:

```
<h3 style="display: inline;">An Inline Heading</h3>
```

However, it's generally recommended you keep all of your styling in a separate file.

### More Information

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jCJan/1/

Comment: Please leave a comment with suggestions for improving an answer if you chose to downvote it.